# Reach Router with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reach-router

I have some code that looks like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Redirect } from '@reach/router';
import Posts from './screens/Posts';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Posts path="posts" />
      <Redirect from="/" to="posts" noThrow default />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

the `default` prop says its invalid on the Redirect is there a way in React to type the children of a component?

it looks like there might be a way to do it using something like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#children-type-checking

but I'm still pretty new to TypeScript so I'm unsure how exactly that would work in practice.

Comment: Maybe you get the error because [there doesn't seem to be a `default` prop on the `Redirect` component](https://reach.tech/router/api/Redirect)?

Comment: A property is not a children of the component. In your example Redirect is a child of Router and default is a property of Redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing [redirects](https://reach.tech/router/api/Redirect) with [default routes](https://reach.tech/router/tutorial/08-default-routes).

**Redirects** are used to rewrite URLs. In your example it seems that you like to redirect the user from '/' to '/posts', so in this case it's correct to use a redirect.

**Default routes** are used to show a component when a unknown path is provided by the user.

So you'd probably create a PageNotFound component and use it like this:

```
<Router>
  <Redirect from="/" to="posts" noThrow />
  <Posts path="posts" />
  <PageNotFound default />
</Router>
```

Since you are using Typescript your PageNotFound component must have a boolean default property in its props, like this:

```
interface Props {
  default: boolean
}

const PageNotFound = (props: Props) => {
  return <div>Page not found</div>;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<Router>
  ...
  <PageNotFound default={true} />
</Router>
```